# Get data from data layer

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, repository

Can you help me? I try to get data from my data layer using firebase. But i'm getting the following error:

```
E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.mvvmlesson, PID: 12328
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must not be empty.
at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.load(Picasso.java:332)
at com.example.mvvmlesson.ui.GameFragment$observeViewModel$1.invoke(GameFragment.kt:54)
at com.example.mvvmlesson.ui.GameFragment$observeViewModel$1.invoke(GameFragment.kt:53)
at com.example.mvvmlesson.ui.GameFragment$sam$androidx_lifecycle_Observer$0.onChanged(Unknown Source:2)
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:133)
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:146)
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$ObserverWrapper.activeStateChanged(LiveData.java:483)
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$LifecycleBoundObserver.onStateChanged(LiveData.java:440)
at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.kt:314)
at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.forwardPass(LifecycleRegistry.kt:251)
at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.sync(LifecycleRegistry.kt:287)
at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.moveToState(LifecycleRegistry.kt:136)
at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(LifecycleRegistry.kt:119)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentViewLifecycleOwner.handleLifecycleEvent(FragmentViewLifecycleOwner.java:100)
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:3194)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.start(FragmentStateManager.java:628)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:290)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1943)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1845)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1782)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:565)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8176)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
```

```
class GameFragment : Fragment() {
    
    private val viewModel: GameViewModel by lazy {
        ViewModelProvider(
            this,
            ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(requireActivity().application)
        )[GameViewModel::class.java]
    }

    private var _binding: FragmentGameBinding? = null
    private val binding: FragmentGameBinding
        get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentGameBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        observeViewModel()
    }

    private fun observeViewModel() {

        viewModel.question.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            Picasso.get().load(it.image.toString()).into(binding.imageViewQuestion)
        }
    }
}
```

```
class GameViewModel: ViewModel() {

    private val repository = GameRepositoryImpl
    
    private val generateQuestionUseCase = GenerateQuestionUseCase(repository)

    private val _question = MutableLiveData<Question>()
    val question: LiveData<Question>
# get() = _question

    fun startGame() {
        generateQuestion()
    }

     private fun generateQuestion() {
        _question.value = generateQuestionUseCase()
    }
}
```

```
object GameRepositoryImpl: GameRepository {

    override fun generateQuestion(): Question {

        val questionGame = Question("", "")

        val db = Firebase.firestore
        val random = (1..5).random()
        val question = db.collection("MOVIES").document(random.toString())
        question.get().addOnSuccessListener { document ->
            val quest = document.toObject<Question>()
            if (quest != null) {
                questionGame.answer = quest.answer.toString()
                questionGame.image = quest.image.toString()
            }
        }
        return questionGame
    }
}
```

```
class GenerateQuestionUseCase (private val repository: GameRepository) {

    operator fun invoke(): Question {
        return repository.generateQuestion()
    }
}
```

```
interface GameRepository {

    fun generateQuestion(): Question
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your repository, the initial values of question are empty (answer and image).  Check the value that you are receiving in the viewmodel because the error said `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must not be empty`.  So I guess that `generateQuestion()` is returning empty values because the operation is not finished yet.  Probably you need to handle the async call to Firebase, using the callback and propagate it or using the suspend coroutines.

For example:

```
`fun generateQuestion(onQuestionLoaded: (Question) -> Unit) {
     val db = Firebase.firestore
     val random = (1..5).random()
     val question = db.collection("MOVIES").document(random.toString())
     question.get().addOnSuccessListener { document ->
         val question = document.toObject<Question>()
         question?.let{
           onQuestionLoaded(it)
         } 
     }
}`
```

Comment: @Andrei nice, then you can mark the answer as useful to help other users.  In the answer, click in the top arrow to push it, thanks!